# Paperclip - how do you upload PDFs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I've got a model that uploads both images and pdfs to Amazon S3 - the images work, the pdfs don't.

This is what my model looks like:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
has_attached_file :pdf,
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/userpdfs/:id/:basename.:extension"
has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {:medium => "200x300>", :thumb => "100x150>" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/userphotos/:style/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

Amazon is showing `userphotos` but no `userpdfs`. Both types have four fields in my database:

```
pdf_name
pdf_type # could also be a word doc
pdf_size
pdf_updated_at
```

1. Why aren't the resumes uploading (the images do!)
2. How can I validate the :pdf field to only allow .pdf, .doc, .docx, .txt?

#### Edit

Uploading any image to the :pdf field works! Something about pdfs themselves seem to mess up the system. My server says it has saved the files to S3 but they don't appear in the directory.

PDFs now work **only if they have no spaces in the title**. With spaces, I get the following error: `Errno::EPIPE: Broken Pipe`.

Comment: You might be able to allow spaces in the file names by wrapping them in double quotes.

Comment: I think better to use `CGI.escape(str)` to deal with spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
>> Attachment.last.file_path
=> "https://s3.amazonaws.com/content.dynamixccw.com/attachments/4/Financial goal Report.pdf"
>> url = _
=> "https://s3.amazonaws.com/content.dynamixccw.com/attachments/4/Financial goal Report.pdf"
>> url.gsub(' ', '%20')
=> "https://s3.amazonaws.com/content.dynamixccw.com/attachments/4/Financial%20goal%20Report.pdf"
```

To validate, throw this in

```
validates_attachment_content_type :pdf, :content_type => ['application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'text/plain'], :if => :pdf_attached?

def pdf_attached?
  self.pdf.file?
end
```

Comment: I'm doing this in my model validates_attachment_content_type :pdf_file, :content_type => ['application/pdf'],:message => "Only PDF files are allowed." but its not working. Any idea? I've also done for presence_of and its working.

Comment: Try `:content_type => ["application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"]`

Comment: Still no error: Please check this I have asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426831/pdf-fileupload-validation-not-working-using-client-side-validation-gem-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

Add this **'application/pdf'** to your **:content_type**, so it becomes **:content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif','application/pdf']**. That should fix it and if you want it opened within the application, then also add **'application/octet-stream'** and for **MSword/spreadsheet**, add **'application/msword'**.

Answer (score 1):

For uploading a pdf document you can just have to do following:

In your model just type

```
validates_attachment_content_type :uploaded_file, :content_type =>['application/pdf']
```

This is working for me, i hope this will help you, All The Best.

Comment: I'm doing this in my model validates_attachment_content_type :pdf_file, :content_type => ['application/pdf'],:message => "Only PDF files are allowed." but its not working. Any idea? I've also done for presence_of and its working